# Trying to parse a JSON string, but always fails

Tags: php, json, gwt, utf-8, jsonlint

This piece of JSON right here:

```
{"user":[{"idUser":"1","username":"USERNAME","userFullName":"FULL NAME","userEmail":"EMAIL@MAIL.COM"}]}
```

Does not validate in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) also not with GWT.

What is strange is that if I delete the first curly brace and type it again, it returns as valid.
Here is the error it gives:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    "user": [   
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Any reason for this? Note that I'm using PHP to generate this string. PHP file used is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: jsonlint says it's valid. At least that's what I get. I think when you first try to validate it, it wasn't exactly a curly bracket.

Comment: It may have originally had some garbage in front of it.

Comment: Ummm, it *does* validate with jsonlint for me.

Comment: Who keeps upvoting questions like this? I don't get it.

Comment: Could be BOM (byte order mark) …

Comment: Looks fine to me.  I don't know what this "jsonlint" thing is of which you speak, but [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) says it is valid.

Comment: it's keeps giving the same error for me. I'm copying the string directly from firebug.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: What are the official requirements for upvoting a question? You may want to check it out on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question

Comment: @webbiedave: Do I want to check out some random question on meta which has no authority whatsoever, when I already know how voting works? No, thanks. Upvote a question when it's useful to others, well-formed and above all _interesting_. This question is clearly not useful to others as it does not describe a problem that actually exists. Almost every question posted seems to get immediately +1'd (but just +1) these days, so I'm starting to think there's a badge troll on the prowl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @knittl for noticing it.

I had the php file encoded in UTF-8.

I changed it to `UTF-8 without BOM` and it worked. I suppose some "garbage" was being returned when I was copying it to jsonlint.

Answer (score 2):

When I copy/paste that into JSONLint, it passes.

You did something else wrong.

Comment: Also, the PHP function `json_decode()` parses this correctly. Tried it [here](http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html).